# C# и кодировка UTF8

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8, кодировка

Есть таблица в MySQL. В ней данные в одном поле хранятся в UTF-8. При чтении получаю вместо кириллицы знаки вопроса. Это если читаю при дебаге проги. Сторонние программы при просмотры таблицы видят кириллицу как положено.
Читаю данные так

```
cmd.CommandText = string.Format("траляля.{0}", proc_name);

object result = null;
if (returns)
    result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
else
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           


return result;
```

Как бы мне указать, что мне нужно переводить данные из utf8?

Comment: я как то пропустил "данные в одном поле", а в остальных полях они в какой кодировке?

Answer (score 2):

Подправьте connection string и добавьте в него в конце строки:

```
charset=utf8
```

или используйте System.Text.Encoding

Comment: А как можно использовать `System.Text.Encoding`, если строка уже запорота?

Comment: Попробуйте сохранить его в байты с указанием кодировки, и прочитать с правильной кодировкой:

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string bad = "ЇЁҐ";
    string good = Convert(bad, 1252, 866);
}

static string Convert(string source, int from, int to)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(from).GetBytes(source);
    return Encoding.GetEncoding(to).GetString(bytes);

Правда это не всегда обратимо, но попробовать стоит..

Comment: если честно я с такой задачей не сталкивался...

Comment: Ну, эээ. Это сработает, если конвертация прошла без потерь. А это вовсе не факт (попробуйте юникодный текст с умляутами прочитать в ASCII-кодировке, а потом восстановить исходный текст). Ну и последовательность действий странная: (1) прочитать байты, сконвертирвоать в неправильную строку. (2) сконвертировать неправильную строку назад в исходные байты. (3) сконвертировать те же байты в правильную строку. Пункты (1) и (2) можно бы выбросить.